# Merge [n-tier] into [n-tier-architecture] (or vice versa)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently there are 2 independent tags:

- [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) (389)
- [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture) (218)

Let's merge one into another and make it synonym.

Comment: Probably sensible, let's get a consensus on which tag would be preferable to keep.

Comment: @TimPost: As far as [n-tier]'s wiki states: "Multi-tier architecture (often referred to as **n-tier architecture**)" looks there is no big difference

Comment: @TimPost I'd opt for [tag:n-tier-architecture] as the master as it's generally more explicit.

Comment: @TimPost: Let's choose one or another, I don't think there is a big difference honestly. The long one is more descriptive though.

Comment: @TimPost: Bump.